# AttributeError: at / 'User' object has no attribute 'standard'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

serializers.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Classname, Sectionname, Teachername, Attendancename
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    standard = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Classname.objects.all())
    section = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Sectionname.objects.all())
    teacher = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Teachername.objects.all())
    attend = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Attendancename.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'standard', 'section', 'teacher', 'attend',)
#when I'm attempting to add 'standard' field it raises above exception.

class ClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Classname
        fields = ('id', 'class_name',)

class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sectionname
        fields = ('id', 'class_name', 'section_name')

class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teachername
        fields = ('id', 'classname', 'secname', 'teachname')

class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendancename
        fields = ('id', 'teacher_name', 'date', 'intime', 'outtime')
```

my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/stu/users/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'student')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  456.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  453.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in get
  199.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  47.         return Response(serializer.data)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  622.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  217.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  572.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  572.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  430.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py" in get_attribute
  367.         relationship = get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
File "C:\Users\User\demo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  71.                 instance = getattr(instance, attr)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /stu/users/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'standard'
```

I'm following a tutorial in DRF. I want to add all my models related primary key reference as above in `'UserSerializer'` but it raises above exception.

As I have four models so I've taken four individual variables in `'UserSerializer'` class and try to show then into User API.

Is I'm doing something wrong? Please provide me your suggestions...

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: You are reffering to the default Django User, the default user has no attributes as the ones you specify in your `UserSerializer` class, if you have a custom User model, use the `get_user_model()` function to refer to your custom model. If not then you need to create the appropriate model or relation.

Answer (score 2):

The default `User` model has no attribute `standard` defined in it.

**Fields defined in Django's `User` model are:**

1. username
2. first_name
3. last_name
4. email
5. password
6. groups
7. user_permissions
8. is_staff
9. is_active
10. is_superuser
11. last_login
12. date_joined

**Your code is not working because there is no `standard` field defined in the `User` model.**

You can instead extend the `User` model and then add the extra `standard`  field  to that Custom User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    standard = models.CharField() # add the 'standard' field
```

Then in your settings, you need to specify this as the user model.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.models.CustomUser'
```

You can use `get_user_model()` function which will return the currently active User model i.e. the `CustomUser` model.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. What you need to provide a `related_name` when creating the `ForeignKey` on your Classname model then when creating the reverse relation on the serializer, you should use the `related_name` as the name for the variable on the serializer. For example:

```py
class Classname(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='standard')

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    standard = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Classname.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'standard', 'section', 'teacher', 'attend',)
```

[Here](http://djangorestframework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations) is the related documentation.